# Why Flexbox doesn't stretch my image's height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

The main element is flex and I set each flex item to 1 for equal width. I notice that the image's height inside the second `flex` item does not stretch. It worked for me when I set the width of the image to `100%`, but it didn't for the `height`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 70rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-2>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item-1">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/pZsBqwD/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="image-header-desktop"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `align-items: center` from `main`, so it would default to `stretch`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; easy fix */
  max-width: 70rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-2>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item-1">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/pZsBqwD/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="image-header-desktop"></div>
</main>
```